# How to run a sql query in Informatica other than source qualifier and lookup?

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have use a query to return one data for one column, but it taking very long time. Can i run this query in middle of pipeline using any other transformation?

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: What makes you think that running a query at the beginning vs. in the middle would make a difference?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: SQL Transformation ? Load a stage table temporarily? Lookup seems like best strategy since this caches your data. You can looks for perf tuning too

Comment: What's the problem here? Performance? Or the fact you need to get the data in the middle of the mapping? How does the query perform when not ran from Informatica? What have you tried so far? Can you share the logs?